# How to check what Julia packages are installed in `jupyter/datascience-notebook`?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab

I'm in Julia x Jupyter project and I chose to use [jupyter/datascience-notebook Docker Image](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook) which contains jupyterlab and Julia environment.

I want to know what package for Julia is pre-installed in `jupyter/datascience-notebook` and know what extra packages I need to install manually.

I read [Dockerfile of datascience-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile) to know what package is installed in the `jupyter/datascience-notebook` image, but I could not find lines for designating julia packages.

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
ARG OWNER=jupyter
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=$OWNER/scipy-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

# Fix DL4006
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

USER root

# Julia installation
# Default values can be overridden at build time
# (ARGS are in lower case to distinguish them from ENV)
# Check https://julialang.org/downloads/
ARG julia_version="1.7.1"

# R pre-requisites
RUN apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    fonts-dejavu \
    gfortran \
    gcc && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Julia dependencies
# install Julia packages in /opt/julia instead of ${HOME}
ENV JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/opt/julia \
    JULIA_PKGDIR=/opt/julia \
    JULIA_VERSION="${julia_version}"

WORKDIR /tmp

# hadolint ignore=SC2046
RUN set -x && \
    julia_arch=$(uname -m) && \
    julia_short_arch="${julia_arch}" && \
    if [ "${julia_short_arch}" == "x86_64" ]; then \
      julia_short_arch="x64"; \
    fi; \
    julia_installer="julia-${JULIA_VERSION}-linux-${julia_arch}.tar.gz" && \
    julia_major_minor=$(echo "${JULIA_VERSION}" | cut -d. -f 1,2) && \
    mkdir "/opt/julia-${JULIA_VERSION}" && \
    wget -q "https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/${julia_short_arch}/${julia_major_minor}/${julia_installer}" && \
    tar xzf "${julia_installer}" -C "/opt/julia-${JULIA_VERSION}" --strip-components=1 && \
    rm "${julia_installer}" && \
    ln -fs /opt/julia-*/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia

# Show Julia where conda libraries are \
RUN mkdir /etc/julia && \
    echo "push!(Libdl.DL_LOAD_PATH, \"${CONDA_DIR}/lib\")" >> /etc/julia/juliarc.jl && \
    # Create JULIA_PKGDIR \
    mkdir "${JULIA_PKGDIR}" && \
    chown "${NB_USER}" "${JULIA_PKGDIR}" && \
    fix-permissions "${JULIA_PKGDIR}"

USER ${NB_UID}

# R packages including IRKernel which gets installed globally.
# r-e1071: dependency of the caret R package
RUN mamba install --quiet --yes \
    'r-base' \
    'r-caret' \
    'r-crayon' \
    'r-devtools' \
    'r-e1071' \
    'r-forecast' \
    'r-hexbin' \
    'r-htmltools' \
    'r-htmlwidgets' \
    'r-irkernel' \
    'r-nycflights13' \
    'r-randomforest' \
    'r-rcurl' \
    'r-rodbc' \
    'r-rsqlite' \
    'r-shiny' \
    'rpy2' \
    'unixodbc' && \
    mamba clean --all -f -y && \
    fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
    fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"

# These packages are not easy to install under arm
RUN set -x && \
    arch=$(uname -m) && \
    if [ "${arch}" == "x86_64" ]; then \
        mamba install --quiet --yes \
            'r-rmarkdown' \
            'r-tidymodels' \
            'r-tidyverse' && \
            mamba clean --all -f -y && \
            fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
            fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"; \
    fi;

# Add Julia packages.
# Install IJulia as jovyan and then move the kernelspec out
# to the system share location. Avoids problems with runtime UID change not
# taking effect properly on the .local folder in the jovyan home dir.
RUN julia -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.update()' && \
    julia -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.add("HDF5")' && \
    julia -e 'using Pkg; pkg"add IJulia"; pkg"precompile"' && \
    # move kernelspec out of home \
    mv "${HOME}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia"* "${CONDA_DIR}/share/jupyter/kernels/" && \
    chmod -R go+rx "${CONDA_DIR}/share/jupyter" && \
    rm -rf "${HOME}/.local" && \
    fix-permissions "${JULIA_PKGDIR}" "${CONDA_DIR}/share/jupyter"

WORKDIR "${HOME}"
```

How can I check out what Julia packages are installed in `jupyter/datascience-notebook`?

Answer (score 5):

In your code `julia -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.add("HDF5")'` installs HDF5 package and it is the only package installed beside of IJulia.

If you want to show the list of packages installed in your Julia environment you can do:

```
julia -e 'using Pkg;Pkg.status()'
```

Looking at your code this will work correctly as long as you run it with the Julia depot location env variable set to: `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/opt/julia`